# Is there formula for $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} sinc((t-nT)/T)$ if $t$ and $T$ is known?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Is there any simple formula for $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} sinc(\frac{t-nT}{T})$, if $t$ and $T$ are given?

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta = t/T$, you want $$f(\theta) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(\theta-n)}{\theta-n} $$
where, I suppose, $\theta$ is real (and the summand is taken to be $1$ when $\theta = n$).
This is the convolution of the $\text{sinc}$ function and the "Dirac comb" $C(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-n)$. Its Fourier transform $\widehat{f}(p)$ is the product of the Fourier transform of the sinc function, which is $\pi$ times the indicator function of the interval $[-1,1]$, and the Fourier transform of the Dirac comb, which is again a Dirac comb with spacing $2\pi$.  The product is
$\pi \delta(p)$, whose inverse Fourier transform is $\pi$.  So we should have $f(\theta) = \pi$.